# Simple modules of quantum toroidal algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

Many properties of quantum toroidal algebras are similar to quantum affine algebras. Every simple module of a quantum affine algebra of rank $n$ corresponds to an $n$-tuple of Drinfeld polynomials.

Has the simple modules of quantum toroidal algebras been classified? Thank you very much.